# MacOs: Good and complete replacement for TortoiseGit

Tags: macos, git, github

I have been using TortoiseGit as a UI for git for a very long time

Alas, this software is not macOS compatible. I am looking for another UI but honestly can't find anything worth it so far.

SourceTree: Don't have basics functions such as force checkout, difficult to get things done
GithubDesktop: No tree (wtf lol ?), and they seem to have decided it will stay this way, users have been complaining for several years and still no tree
GitKraken: Unreadable

Do you have a suggestion of an actual good product I can use and won't take 3x the time tortoise require to do basics actions ? Also one that will not do stuff I did not request (allo GithubDesktop ?)

My most used actions are `fetch`, `pull`, `rebase`, `checkout`, `reset`, `stash`, `clean`, with all applicable options. And obviously I need the tree because I am constantly comparing commits to one another.

Answer (score 0):

here is an option: [GitTower](https://www.git-tower.com/mac)

- it does basic stuff
- agree that Kraken is busy
- have never used Tortoise but my teammates like it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).